# How can I enlarge the font for viewing the Dolphin handbook?

Tags: fonts, dolphin

I'm running Kubuntu 21.10. How can I enlarge the font for viewing the Dolphin Handbook? I've already set the font in System Settings to 16pt and similarly for the font in Firefox.

Comment: I see that you've asked a lot of questions about how to enlarge fonts in various applications. That's not always easy to do and is definitely not consistent between applications. Have you tried to use a screen magnifier? That would be a much easier path and will allow you to enlarge anything on demand.

Comment: I use a screen magnifier (Ctl-+) when I need to, but there ought to be a more general solution.  Perhaps the font settings in System Settings should overrule everything else.  The problem is that once you've fixed the font in System Settings and the browser, it's very hard to know what else to do.